# what is the difference in the delay of before and after non-blocking statements inside a loop?

Tags: verilog

what is the difference between this two code snippets?

```
    always @(posedge clk) begin
            r3 <= @(posedge clk) 1;
            r2 <= @(posedge clk) 1;
            ready = 0;
            while (r2 <= n) begin
                r2 <= @(posedge clk) r2 + 1;     <--- never stops executing
            end
    end


    always @(posedge clk) begin
            r3 <= @(posedge clk) 1;
            r2 <= @(posedge clk) 1;
            ready = 0;
            while (r2 <= n) begin
                @(posedge clk) r2 <= r2 + 1;     <--- normally executes
            end
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the simulator executes `r2 <= @(posedge clk) r2 + 1`, it performs the following steps:

- evaluate `r2 + 1`
- schedule a non-blocking assignment (NBA) update event to be executed at the next posedge clk

When the simulator executes `@(posedge clk) r2 <= r2 + 1`, it performs the following steps:

- suspend the `always` process and schedule it to resume at the next posedge clk
- when the process resumes, execute the `r2 <= r2 + 1` NBA, by doing the following:

  - evaluate `r2 + 1`
  - schedule an NBA update event for the current time

The first form parses as a non-blocking assignment, and executes in zero time. The delay only applies to the update event generated when the NBA executes. The second form parses as a statement delay control followed by an NBA. It does not execute in zero time because the delay applies to the execution of the statement rather than just the update event.

The first form is an infinite loop because the body of the `while` loop executes in zero time and the events that will increment `r2` are scheduled for a future time.

With the second form, you will still want to be careful about boundary conditions when the loop terminates. After scheduling an update that sets `r2` to `n + 1`, the condition will evaluate as true one more time before that update is applied.

Comment: It should be noted that it's not usual to see `@(posedge clk)` statements sprinkled through code like that either.

Comment: @Marty, is it a bad practice having `@(posedge clk)` statements scattered in my code?

Comment: @19293001: It is, especially for code that needs to be synthesised. In fact, I doubt if a synthesis tool will even look at it!